# Value of lim $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac xn \ln\left(\frac{x}{n} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

How can I calculate this limit?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac xn \ln\left(\frac{x}{n} \right)$$

I think it is a $0 \cdot \infty$ case, but I have no other ideas. I looked again at the properties of $\ln$, thinking that it might help me, but I still didn't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Apply L'Hopital's Rule to $\\lim_{t \to 0}\frac {\ln t} {1/t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $t:= \frac{n}{x}$, then the limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{t} = -\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln(t)}{t}$$
Now, since $\ln(x) < x$, we have
$$0 \le \frac{\ln(t)}{t} = \frac{2\color{red}{\ln\left(\sqrt t\right)}}{\sqrt t \color{red}{\sqrt t}}\le \frac{2}{\sqrt t}\cdot\color{red}1$$ Therefore,$$ 
0 \le \frac{\ln(t)}{t} \le \frac{2}{\sqrt t}$$
Finally, by squeeze theorem, we have
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln(t)}{t} = 0$$
which also means that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac xn \ln\left(\frac{x}{n} \right)= 0$$

Comment: Actually, $\frac xn\ln\left(\frac xn\right)<0$ if $n>x$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. I hope it is correct now $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x)=0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac xn\ln\left(\frac xn\right)=0$.